# Passing header data with a URLSession in a MacOS app, getting nil response

Tags: swift, nsurlrequest, urlsession

I have to make a URLSession call where I pass basic auth and also some other POST data, but I am not sure if I am setting it up correctly. I am getting a nil response. The process is making a search query of a documentation database.

To make the query I have to make two calls, one to get the auth ticket, the next to pass the ticket and the search query.

I have a general URLRequest function and pass flags in for what it needs to do (read cookies, set cookies, auth, etc.) then I pass that request to a general URLSession function.

The relevant section of the request function for getting a ticket is:

```
//if we are getting the ticket
    if bGetTicket {
        if let dictData = dictData {
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            
            if dictData.count > 0 {
                request.setValue("Application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictData, options: []) else {
                    print("Could not  convert dictData to JSON.")
                    return
                }
                request.httpBody = httpBody
            }
        } else {
            strErrMsg.append("There was a problem with the POST data, it was nil.\n\n")
            bIsValid = false
        }//end data check
    }//bGetTicket
```

that works fine but when I try to do the search query I am getting a nil response:

```
if bIsAuth {
        if let dictData = dictData {
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            if dictData.count > 0 {
                
                if let strTicket = dictData["ticket"] as? String, let dictQuery = dictData["dictQuery"] as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                    request.setValue("Application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                    request.setValue("Basic \(strTicket)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
                    
                    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictQuery, options: []) else {
                        print("Could not  convert dictData to JSON.")
                        return
                    }
                    request.httpBody = httpBody
                }
            }
        } else {
            strErrMsg.append("There was a problem with the POST data, it was nil.\n\n")
            bIsValid = false
        }//end data check
    }//end isAuth
```

The format for search data is:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query": "dog"
    }
}
```

and the dictionary I am converting to JSON follows that pattern:

```
["query": ["query": "PSP"]]
```

I am getting nil on the response and when I look at the headers of the request the search data is not being attached:

```
Optional(["Content-Type": "Application/json", "Authorization": "Basic TICKET_184e995ed8ea09881c3ba6edcf929c03ac7e283e"])
```

Could someone point out where I am going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: "when I look at the headers of the request the search data is not being attached:" didn't you put it in `httpBody`? You only printed headers, not body.

Comment: What is a guy named dictData, and where does it come from?

Comment: @Larme Duh, you're right, long day. : ) The search query is attached to the body: 

let stringValue = String(decoding: request.httpBody!, as: UTF8.self)
        print(stringValue)

produces the expected results.

Comment: @ElTomato dictData is the POST data I am passing to the request: 

 func setUpRequest(_ strURL:String, _ bGetTicket:Bool, _ dictData:NSMutableDictionary?, _ bIsAuth:Bool, _ bSendCookie:Bool, _ bSetCookie:Bool, completed:@escaping returnDictClosure) {

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the Authorization field is **explicitly forbidden** according to the [NSURLSession documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/1411532-httpadditionalheaders).  It works in some situations, but not generally.

If you're doing basic auth, you **must** use the actual auth features of the API, or else the value you pass in will likely get overwritten.